# D3.js transition callback on frame

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

Does anyone know how I could accomplish a per frame callback for a transition with D3. Here is and example of what I am doing currently.

```
link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal)
    .each("end",function(e) {
        if(e.target.id == current)
            show_tooltip(e.target)
    });
```

This currently calls the anonymous function for each element at the end of the animation. I would like to call it for every frame.

Answer (score 5):

You can register a custom tween that returns the function that you want called every tick.

```
link.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", diagonal)
  .tween("side-effects", function() {
    return function() {
      console.log(d3.select(this), "tick");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the D3 documentation at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#timers

The timer queue will callback [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)

You should be able to use this to implement your transitions.